# Android Studio Adapter table layout with searchView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a problem in data filtering, where the first row is not read when data filtering is done

[image]

[image]

for example in the image above, the word that has the letters "Ore" should display 3 data, but the first data is not readable, only 2 data appear

my adapter :

```
public class AdapterProduct extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterProduct.userViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<String> prodcode, prodname, satuan,edited;
    DBStock dbStock;

    AdapterProduct(Activity activity, Context context, ArrayList prodcode, ArrayList prodname, ArrayList satuan, ArrayList edited) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.context = context;
        this.prodcode = prodcode;
        this.prodname = prodname;
        this.satuan = satuan;
        this.edited = edited;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public userViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_m_product_detail, parent, false);
        return new userViewHolder(view);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final userViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {

        int rowPos  = holder.getAdapterPosition();
        if (rowPos  == 0) {
            holder.txtadpprodcode.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_header_cell_bg);
            holder.txtadpprodname.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_header_cell_bg);
            holder.txtadpsatuan.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_header_cell_bg);
            holder.txtadpedit.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_header_cell_bg);

            holder.txtadpprodcode.setText("Item Code");
            holder.txtadpprodcode.setGravity(1);
            holder.txtadpprodcode.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

            holder.txtadpprodname.setText("Item Name");
            holder.txtadpprodname.setGravity(1);
            holder.txtadpprodname.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);


            holder.txtadpsatuan.setText("Satuan");
            holder.txtadpsatuan.setGravity(1);
            holder.txtadpsatuan.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

            holder.txtadpedit.setText("Option");
            holder.txtadpedit.setGravity(1);
            holder.txtadpedit.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

        } else  {

            holder.txtadpprodcode.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_content_cell_bg);
            holder.txtadpprodname.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_content_cell_bg);
            holder.txtadpedit.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_content_cell_bg);
            holder.txtadpsatuan.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_content_cell_bg);

            holder.txtadpprodcode.setText(String.valueOf(prodcode.get(position)));
            holder.txtadpprodname.setText(String.valueOf(prodname.get(position)));
            holder.txtadpsatuan.setText(String.valueOf(satuan.get(position)));
            holder.txtadpedit.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_more_vert_24);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return prodname.size();
    }

    class userViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {
        TextView txtadpprodcode , txtadpprodname, txtadpedit, txtadpsatuan;
        userViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtadpprodcode = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtprodcode);
            txtadpprodname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtprodname);
            txtadpedit = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtedit);
            txtadpsatuan = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtsatuan);
            txtadpedit.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showOptMenu(v);

        }

        private void showOptMenu(View viewopt) {
            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(viewopt.getContext(), viewopt);
            popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.opt_menuproduct);

            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
            popupMenu.show();

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

            dbStock = new DBStock(txtadpedit.getContext());

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.opteditproduct:

                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(txtadpedit.getContext(), R.style.DialogStyle);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_editproduct);
                    dialog.setCancelable(false);
                    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    dialog.show();

                    Button btNo = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_no);
                    Button btYes = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_yes);


                    final EditText edprodcode = dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtprodcode);
                    final EditText edprodname = dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtprodname);
                    final Spinner Spinuom = dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinnerSatuan);

                    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterworkstatus = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(txtadpedit.getContext(), R.array.array_satuan, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                    adapterworkstatus.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    Spinuom.setAdapter(adapterworkstatus);

                    edprodcode.setText(txtadpprodcode.getText());
                    edprodname.setText(txtadpprodname.getText());

                    btNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    btYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            dbStock.updateMProduct(edprodcode.getText().toString(),edprodname.getText().toString(), Spinuom.getSelectedItem().toString());
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }

                    });
                    dialog.show();

                    return true;

                case R.id.optdeleteproduct:

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(txtadpedit.getContext());
                    builder.setTitle("DELETE");
                    builder.setMessage("Are You Sure Delete This Product?");
                    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int id) {
                            dbStock.removeMProduct(txtadpprodcode.getText().toString());
                            adapterrefresh();
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int id) {
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();

                    return true;

                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void filterList(ArrayList<String> filterdNames) {
        this.prodname = filterdNames;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void adapterrefresh() {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

in Activity

```
    public class MasterProduct extends AppCompatActivity {
    DBStock dbStock;
    RecyclerView recyclerView, recyclerView2;
    ArrayList<String> prodcode, prodname, satuan,edited;
    AdapterProduct adapterProduct;
    String sProdCode, sProdName,sUOM;
    EditText edSearch;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_m_product);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.viewbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Master Product");

        dbStock = new DBStock(this);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        edSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtfilter);

        prodcode = new ArrayList<>();
        prodname = new ArrayList<>();
        satuan = new ArrayList<>();
        edited = new ArrayList<>();

        adapterProduct = new AdapterProduct(MasterProduct.this, this, prodcode, prodname, satuan,edited);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterProduct);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MasterProduct.this));

        storeDataFromDBLocal();
        //SetAdapter();

        edSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                filter(s.toString());

            }
        });

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.opt_menuproductadd, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.optAdd:
                showdialogaddproduct();
                return true;

            case R.id.optImport:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MasterProduct.this, ImportProduct.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;

            case R.id.optclear:
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("DELETE ALL PRODUCT");
                builder.setMessage("Are You Sure Clear Data Product?");
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int id) {
                        dbStock.removeAllMproduct();
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int id) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;

        }
    }

    void storeDataFromDBLocal(){
        Cursor cursor = dbStock.getMProduct();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                prodcode.add(cursor.getString(0));
                prodname.add(cursor.getString(1));
                satuan.add(cursor.getString(2));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }

    public void ShowToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void showdialogaddproduct() {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.DialogStyle);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_addproduct);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.show();

        Button btNo = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_no);
        Button btYes = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_yes);

        final EditText edprodcode = dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtprodcode);
        final EditText edprodname = dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtprodname);
        final Spinner Spinuom = dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinnerSatuan);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterworkstatus = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.array_satuan, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapterworkstatus.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        Spinuom.setAdapter(adapterworkstatus);

        btNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        btYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sProdCode = edprodcode.getText().toString();
                sProdName = edprodname.getText().toString();
                sUOM = Spinuom.getSelectedItem().toString();

                dbStock.addDataMProduct(sProdCode,sProdName,sUOM);
                adapterProduct.adapterrefresh();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }

    private void filter(String text) {
        ArrayList<String> filterdNames = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String s : prodname) {
                //if the existing elements contains the search input
                if (s.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
                    //adding the element to filtered list
                    filterdNames.add(s);
                }
            }
            adapterProduct.filterList(filterdNames);
        }

}
```

help me fix it if something is wrong
thanks...